# How can the Object class be a super class of subclasses?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

**Fact 1:**

> Java does not support multiple inheritance.

**Fact 2:**

> Object is a superclass of all other classes

If I have a class `Parent` and a class `Child` which is inheriting the class `Parent`:

```
class Parent {

}

class Child extends Parent {

}
```

In this case, how will the class `Child` inherit the `Object` class, if Java does not support multiple inheritance?

How is the relationship between these three defined?

**Option 1:**

[image]

**Option 2:**

[image]

Comment: `Object` is the superclass of every class in Java.

Comment: Your `fact 1` is a actually a bit outdated, and the doc from which you probably took your `fact 2` should clearly tell that your Option 2 is the right one.

Comment: @JeremyGrand how is fact1 outdated? I am reading from The Complete Reference Ed 7. Does the new version of Java support multiple inheritance?

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri, you seem to have mistaken `multilevel` with `multiple` inheritence.

Comment: @Arvind `multilevel inheritance` and `multiple inheritance` are not the same things. Java supports the `multilevel inheritance`, but C++ does both.

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri the Ed7 is eleven years old. Since java 8 (2014), java kinda allows multiple inheritance through the use of default methods in interface. That's not as a straigthforward multiple inheritance as you would have in C++, but the outcome is close to it.

Comment: @JeremyGrand thanks for clarifying it, will read about `default` in detail.

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri a note to the solution you've posted: you couldn't create instances to get their classes: `Parent.class` is an equivalent to `new Parent().getClass()`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yeah that would be better, I will update the solution.

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri try to avoid raw types as well, use `Class<T>` instead of `Class`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko What's the difference between the two?

Comment: `Class<T>` have specified class names so they are attached to that class?

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri it's safer and beneficial: the result of `Parent.class.newInstance()` can be stored into a `Parent` variable (since `Parent.class` returns `Class<Parent>`) while `rawClassVariable.newInstance()` can't.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko How will I use `class<T>` for getting `Object` class? Using `class<Object>` gives `incompatible types: Class<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Class<Object>`

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri `Class<Object> c = Object.class;` shoud compile, while `Class<Object> c = Parent.class;` shouldn't. Actually, `Parent.class` is a `Class<? extend Object>`, not a `Class<Object>`.

Comment: please don't post answers/solutions in questions but feel free to write a new answer instead and mark it as accepted if you may think that's the real solution to your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @AndrewTobilko updated the code, thanka for all the help :)

Comment: @fantaghirocco I can't answer it myself if I didn't check the `self-answer` field while posting the question. That field can't be updated now.

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri yes you can - just use the answer box below. All "self-answer" does is display an answer box on the question field. But do you need to post an answer at all? Seems like there is already a perfectly good answer, which you have accepted.

Comment: @AntP I will remove the **Solution** part. Your argument makes sense.

Comment: thank you @Abhishek : it's only in order to avoid the introduction of new behaviours since the users already know the SO model. Anyway you can also [edit the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) by adding what you consider a relevant par of your solution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's Option 2. If you define a superclass, that will be the immediate superclass of your class. If you don't define one, `Object` will be the immediate superclass.

```
class Parent {

}

class Child extends Parent {

}
```

is equivalent to

```
class Parent extends Object {

}

class Child extends Parent {

}
```

So, while `Object` is the superclass of all classes, there might be some steps in the class hierarchy before you get to `Object`. It's not the immediate superclass of all classes.

Comment: Won't `class Child` also inherit `Object`? Won't it be `class Child extends Parent, Object` (if it's possible internally somehow!!!)?

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri No. Child inherits Object **through** Parent.

Answer (score 9):

`Object` might not be a direct parent, but it's always a super parent.

```
Child extends Parent
Parent extends Object

 |
 V

Child [indirectly] extends Object
```

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri if the scenario 1 were correct, we would encounter the problem of choosing methods for the subclass (since both `Object` and `Parent extends Object` have the same set of methods including `equals`, `hashCode`, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) says:

> Class `Object` is the root of the class hierarchy. ...

If a class does not extend any other class by decalring it using the keyword `extends` it extends though implicit from `Object`.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) says:

> In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is
>   implicitly a subclass of Object.

See the [Example 8.1.4-1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#d5e12064) "*Direct Superclasses and Subclasses*" in [JLS, chapter 8.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4)

It shows that a `class Point { int x, y; }` "*is a direct subclass of Object*"

Moreover the documentation says:

> Classes can be derived from classes that are derived from classes that
>   are derived from classes, and so on, and ultimately derived from the
>   topmost class, `Object`. Such a class is said to be descended from all
>   the classes in the inheritance chain stretching back to `Object`.

The JLS states it short and formal:

> The subclass relationship is the transitive closure of the direct
>   subclass relationship.

Thus class `Object` is the superclass of all classes.

But the documentation also says:

> Excepting `Object`, which has no superclass, every class has one and only one direct superclass (single
>   inheritance).

Going on with the example a `class ColoredPoint extends Point { int color; }` "*is a direct subclass of class `Point`.*". By the transitive relationship it's a (non-direct) subclass of class `Object`.

Summarizing:
`Object` is either the direct superclass or by transitive relationship the last superclass of any other class.

Answering the questions:

- *Java does not support multiple inheritance*: It provides single inheritence in a transitive way. Every class extends directly only one supercalss.
- *How is the relationship*: The class `Parent` corresponds to the class `Point` and the class `Child` to the class `ColoredPoint` of the JLS example. Only *Option 2* shows this relation.

Answer (score 5):

Well it is an interesting discussion. I think it will be option no 2. As if you try the below code .

```
public static void main(String []args){
      Parent p=new Parent();
      Class c= p.getClass();

      Child child =new Child();
      Class c1= child.getClass();
      System.out.println(c.getSuperclass());
      System.out.println(c1.getSuperclass());

 }
```

You will get output as :

```
class java.lang.Object 
class Parent
```

Comment: using the following code solved my doubt: `Class child_super = c1.getSuperclass();
       System.out.println(child_super.getSuperclass());`

Answer (score 3):

Option 2, as every object derives Object.class methods

Answer (score 3):

The right answer is Option 2. Any Java class inherit all parents for their parents. In other words.

Class A extends Class B
Class B extends Class C
Class C extends Class D

Class X extends A -> it means that A inherit all protected/package/public fields from B,C and D.

In your example, Class Child inherit Parent properties but also Object properties in transitive mode.

Answer (score 3):

From [`Class Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

> `public class Object`
> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy.
> Every class has Object as a superclass.
>  All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

This means that every Java class has `Object` as root in the hierarchy, not necessarily as its immediate parent.

Answer (score 3):

No multiple inheritance means in Java a class extends only 1 class; has one immediate base class. Indirectly a class can have many ancestors: Child has Parent and Object as ancestor "super" classes.

```
Object --> Parent --> Child
                  --> OtherChild

Relation: 1 --> N
```

The reason for avoiding multiple inheritance like in C++, was the ambiguity involved:

***Pseudo code assuming multiple inheritance:***

```
class A : Comparable
class B : Comparable

class Child : A, B {

    @Override A? B?
    int compareTo(Child rhs) { ... super.compareTo ? ... }
}

A a = new Child();
B b = new Child();
a.compareTo(b);
```

Comment: why should we care about which method to override if the signatures are identical? Overriding just implies that we are not satisfied with parents' behaviour and want to implement ours. The problem is, rather, what happens when we call `child.compareTo(anotherChild)` without overriding (which method are we going to invoke?)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko well said; `compareTo(a); compareTo(b), compareTo(child)`; actually I did not want to say anything about multiple inheritance (and interfaces) as that would be out of scope of the question. Just that multiple inheritance is _not_ having an ancestral line; rather that single inheritance means having one (code bearing) parent per class. I also did not treat default methods in interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, **using Java 8, it is possible** to accomplish [Multiple inheritance using Default methods of interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/multipleinheritance.html).

Secondly, your understanding regarding Object class is correctly represented in 'Option 2'. 
However, it is not multiple inheritance, rather multilevel inheritance. 'Option 1' is multiple inheritance.

Please check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#Types) to read more about them.

Answer (score 2):

option 2.Object is a superclass of all other classes,but Object may not a dirrect superclass of a classe.